# C# Add item to list

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a list like so:

```
List<string> songs = new List<string>();
```

and many objects in the form of:

```
{'artist' => '....', 'title' => '.....', 'discnumber' => '...'}
```

Which are being created in a loop. What I am trying to do is add the object to the list.

Thanks

Comment: so you have an object and you want to list all values?

Comment: could you show a real example with input and desired output ?

Comment: "What I am trying to do is add the object to the list." A worthy challenge! Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Obviously, you cannot put in objects which contain all that data into a list of strings, unless you create strings which contain all data separated by some character.

Comment: what constitutes an object in your context, if {'artist'=>'...',...,.} is an array then how its being build ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to create a custom class `Song` with properties like `Artist`,`Title` or `Discnumber`. Then use a `List<Song>` instead.

However, if you want to use your strings instead, i assume that you want to keep a csv-format:

```
foreach( <your Loop> )
{
    songs.Add(String.Join(",", objects));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If those are all the object of type string you can add like follows,

```
List<string> songs = new List<string>(); 
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    songs.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Or if you want Key,Value type, you can use dictionary,

```
Dictionary<string, String> Info = new List<string>(); 
Info.Add("Artist", "Some Artist");
Info.Add("Track", "Some Track");
//You can access the value as follows
string artist = info["Artist"]
```